# Node static route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a routing problem in my app. My filesystem looks like

```
/allure-report
/allure-report/index.html
/public
/public/index.html
/start.js
```

I have set express and static route to public

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Now calling the node server it will send my html code well.

```
res.send(myHtmlCode);
```

But it will crash if I want to use in a different button click:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/allure-report/index.html');
```

Following the documentation  I added:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('allure-report'));
```

In the documentation is written that it will use the search order how I added the paths. But in this case the app will always present the allure-report/index.html" and not my own html. This is very confusing.

Without the allure static route, the sendfile will do nothing. The old page will not change.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to say, best post the error, also what you are getting and what is expected in the question.